# Search Persian/Arabic numbers in html files?

Tags: notepad++, html

I have in about 50 html files that are about bank payments of a company.I have to search in about serial numbers in files.I use `Agent Ransack` for searching in contents of files.But my problem is in about format of numbers in `HTML` files that is persian/arabic;like `۲۶۴۲۰۸۵۷`.But this number is not stored in the source as `26420857`.Really it is stored in the source of html file as a String like this: `&#1777;&#1779;&#1785;&#1778;/&#1777;&#1777;/&#1778;&#1781;` !

So when I try to find a file that contains `26420857`,the result will be empty.How I can solve this problem?

I try to convert numbers to `&#` format,but I do not know how I can do it.Also I try to use notepad++ to convert `&#` format numbers to usual numbers,but I could not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Microsoft Word to read in the HTML, and then save it to a "plain text" file while specifying the encoding as either UTF-8 or Arabic ISO. I suppose you could search within Word for the Arabic text without saving the file too.

Alternatively, if the HTML page is in Arabic and not mixed English/Arabic, you could try [google translate](http://translate.google.com).
It takes both URL links or you could just copy/paste the html contents directly.

Comment: I use `google translate` and it works,but,there is no direct way to convert Arabic numbers to English?